# Java Convert String to Array "[1,2,3,4,5,5]" to [1,2,3,4,5,5]

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to convert a string which is a in the format

```
String x= "[\"a\",\"1\"]" ;
```

to

```
String [] vals =["a" , "1"];
```

I am currently doing it in two steps

1. removing the [ & ] from the string
2. Splitting the string with at the comma character

> `String x2="\"a\",\"1\""`

> `x2.split(",")`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, convert the string to array of integers?

Comment: I wanted to know about the best practice to convert String  to a String [] , it can be a array to strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I exactly, don't gather whether you want an array of Strings or an array of Integer as your result, but for the example, you have provided, this should work.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "[\"a\",\"1\"]";
        String[] array = x.split("\"");
        array = Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i.matches("[\\dA-Za-z]")).toArray(String[]::new);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); 
    }
}
```

I have filtered the array because initially there will be some empty strings and opening and closing braces as strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ObjectMapper on the string

```
List list = new ObjectMapper().readValue(x, List.class); // list of object
```

cast them to your required class

Comment: Hello All , all the answers working , thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JSONArray` in the `org.json` package to parse the string as an array.

```java
import org.json.JSONArray;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "[\"a\",\"1\"]";
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(x);
        String [] stringArray = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            stringArray[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
        }
    }
}
```

For integer arrays, you can use `getInt(i)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Sai Ashish Das answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67444397/15510171) is working well. But I recommnad to use generics through TypeReference  for type safe.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
List<String> result = om.readValue("[\"a\",\"1\"]", new TypeReference<List<String>>() {});

result.forEach(System.out::println); // a , 1
```